# CiviCRM 5.50 Fatal Memory Error on the Status page

Tags: civimail

I recently upgraded to CiviCRM 5.5 on an Apache2 server with PHP 7.4

Now, when I attempt to open the CiviCRM status page I get an HTTP error 500, and this also happens when trying to create a new mailing (either Mosaico or traditional)

I think also that Civi Cron is erroring, as every 5 minutes in Apache2 error.log I see:

```
[Fri Jun 03 19:05:02.797134 2022] [php7:error] [pid 2718] [client 95.172.20.13:54108] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /var/www/XXX/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Token/Event/TokenRegisterEvent.php on line 67
[Fri Jun 03 19:05:02.797939 2022] [php7:error] [pid 2718] [client 95.172.20.13:54108] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /var/www/XXX/wp-includes/class-wp-fatal-error-handler.php on line 73
[Fri Jun 03 19:05:02.798448 2022] [php7:error] [pid 2718] [client 95.172.20.13:54108] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /var/www/XXX/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 189
```

(XXX not the real folder name) I have tried enabling CiviCRM logging but it doesn't reveal anything more useful. I've tried enabling PHP error notices but am still seeing a 'friendly' HTTP error 500 in Chrome.

I've also tried temporarily disabling Mosaico.

Would really appreciate any assistance in debugging this further, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running the extension upgrades. Go to the Manage Extensions page, and it should display a notice to upgrade extensions.

Alternatively, try going to https://example.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Fextensions&reset=1 (replace example.org with your website).

I think this is specific to CiviCRM 5.50, when SearchKit is enabled. There are [discussions here](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/3490) on how to avoid this problem in the future.

Comment: Thank you, this pointed me to the problem-a custom extension. Once disabled, all is fine!